# How to access map values in groovy by key containing dot?

Tags: groovy, dictionary

I have map like this:

```
data = {user.name: "John",
        user.surname: "Doe",
        city: "NY"}
```

I can access attiribute 'city' this way:

```
data.city
```

Is there is a similar way to access 'user.name' attribute?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
data = [ 'user.name':"John", 'user.surname':"Doe", city:"NY" ]
```

(square braces for the map definition, and quotes round the dotted key names), I believe that

```
data.'user.name'
```

should do it