# Parsing properties files in groovy where keys contain dot (.) and use as templating binding

Tags: templates, groovy

This is pretty common in Java-world having properties files with dot (.) in the key. Maven and Gradle solves this problem naturally but now I need to do this in plain groovy:

```
def propertiesFileContent = 'a.b=http://my.com/test'
def templateContent = 'Testing ${a.b} '

def props = new Properties()
props.load(new StringReader(propertiesFileContent))
def template = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(templateContent)
println template.make(props)
```

The above code throws exception because the template engine threats ${a.b} as 'b' field of the 'a' object and do not accept 'a.b=http://my.com/test' to substitute.
First I thought it is a bug in groovy templating but now it seems that this is a well-known limitation, and everybody suggests solutions that needs the modification of the template:

- [Get values from properties file using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871441/get-values-from-properties-file-using-groovy#answer-38956236)
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8041
- [How to access map values in groovy by key containing dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730620/how-to-access-map-values-in-groovy-by-key-containing-dot)

I'm in a situation where I should do this without the chance to modify the properties file or the template itself: they are in TAGged and released version of the application :-(
Is there a solution or workaround if those are not possible?
(I tried to use FreeMarker templating but facing the same issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `groovy.util.ConfigSlurper#parse(java.util.Properties)`. Usage:

```
template.make(new ConfigSlurper().parse(props))
```

`template.make()` expects an object containing template properties, for example:

```
[a: [b: 'http://my.com/test']]
```

`ConfigSlurper` does exactly what is needed converting `Properties` instance to such an object.